# XSLT two column unordered list

Tags: jquery, html, css, xml, xslt

I need help with xsl transformation. I have xml being spitted out by SharePoint Server control as below:

```
<rows>
    <row>A</row>
    <row>B</row>
    <row>C</row>
    <row>D</row>
    <row>E</row>
    <row>F</row>
    <row>G</row>
    <row>H</row>
</rows>
```

I need to transform the above xml into below:

```
  <==  A-----------B  ==> An li sliding back and forth with the help of a slider plugin
       C-----------D
       E-----------F
       G-----------H
```

LIKE THIS:
[image: Like this]
<sub>(source: [imagesup.net](http://www.imagesup.net/?di=1135653604016))</sub>

Required HTML in the following format as that's how the slider plugin demands the html be rendered as for it to work:

```
<div class="content-carousel">
<!-- start Basic Jquery Slider -->
        <ul class="bjqs">
          <li>
              <div class="content-left">
               <h4>A</h4>
               </div>
              <div class="content-right">
               <h4>B</h4>
               </div>
          </li>
        <li>
              <div class="content-left">
               <h4>C</h4>
               </div>
              <div class="content-right">
               <h4>D</h4>
               </div>
          </li>
          .
          .
        </ul>
</div>
```

HERE IS THE ACTUAL RAW XML: https://gist.github.com/4380967

Here is the bjqs slider plugin requirement:
[image: plugin]
<sub>(source: [imagesup.net](http://www.imagesup.net/?di=11135653673210))</sub>

WHAT I HAVE CURRENTLY: I am able to get two column layout but tables rows are involved to do so , which emits unnecessary markups not good for the slider plugin. So for each row, the following applies:

```
 <xsl:if test="$CurPos = 1 ">
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;div&gt;&lt;table&gt;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="$CurPos mod 2 = 1">
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;tr&gt;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:if> 
 
<li>
  <td width="50%" valign="top">
    <table width="90%">
      <tr height="35px" min-height="35px" valign="top">
        <td>
          <span>
            <xsl:if test="string-length($SafeImageUrl) != 0">
              <div class="image-area-left">
                <a href="{$SafeLinkUrl}" target="{$LinkTarget}">
                  <img class="image" src="{$SafeImageUrl}" alt="{@ImageUrlAltText}" />
                </a>
              </div>
            </xsl:if>
            
            <H3>
                <a href="{$SafeLinkUrl}"> <xsl:value-of select="@Title"/> </a>
            </H3>
            <div class="newsgist"><xsl:value-of select="substring(@Comments,0,200)"/>
                <xsl:if test="string-length(@Comments) &gt; 200">…</xsl:if>         <a href="{$SafeLinkUrl}"> Details…</a>  
            </div>
          </span> 
        </td>
      </tr>
 
    </table>
  </td></li>
 
  <xsl:if test="$CurPos mod 2 = 0">
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;/tr&gt;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="$CurPos = $LastRow ">
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;/table&gt;&lt;/div&gt;</xsl:text>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
     <div class="content-carousel">
     <ul class="bjqs">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[position() mod 2 =1]"/>
     </ul>
   </div>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="row">
   <li>
     <div class="content-left">
        <h4><xsl:value-of select="."/></h4>
     </div>
       <div class="content-right">
         <h4><xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::*[1]"/></h4>
       </div>
  </li>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<rows>
    <row>A</row>
    <row>B</row>
    <row>C</row>
    <row>D</row>
    <row>E</row>
    <row>F</row>
    <row>G</row>
    <row>H</row>
</rows>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<div class="content-carousel">
   <ul class="bjqs">
      <li>
         <div class="content-left">
            <h4>A</h4>
         </div>
         <div class="content-right">
            <h4>B</h4>
         </div>
      </li>
      <li>
         <div class="content-left">
            <h4>C</h4>
         </div>
         <div class="content-right">
            <h4>D</h4>
         </div>
      </li>
      <li>
         <div class="content-left">
            <h4>E</h4>
         </div>
         <div class="content-right">
            <h4>F</h4>
         </div>
      </li>
      <li>
         <div class="content-left">
            <h4>G</h4>
         </div>
         <div class="content-right">
            <h4>H</h4>
         </div>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: How would you get the row attributes value if it was something like this? <rows>
    <row title="A' /><row title="B' /><row title="C' /><row title="D' /></Rows>

Comment: @SarikaThapaliya, by replacing '.' with `@title`

Comment: and following-sibling's title as following-sibling::*[1]/@title?

Comment: Why does mine repeat like this? A--B B--C C--D? I am using this?    <div class="content-left" style="width:250px; float:left;">
 <span class="NewsHeading"><h4><xsl:value-of select="@Title"/></h4></span>
  </div>
   <div class="content-right" style="float:right">
  <span class="NewsHeading"><h4><xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::*[1]/@Title"/></h4></span>
    </div>

Comment: @SarikaThapaliya, Please, ask a new question, Your current question was completely answered, and comments aren't suitable for sharing code.