# for each odd numbered row xsl

Tags: xslt, xpath

How do I do `for-each` for all the **odd** **numbered** rows?
XML looks like this:

```
<dsQueryResponse ViewStyleID="" BaseViewID="" TemplateType="" RowLimit="">
  <Rows>
    <Row title="A"/>
    <Row title="B"/>
    <Row title="C"/>
    <Row title="D"/>
    <Row title="E"/>
    <Row title="F"/>
</Rows>
</dsQueryResponse>
```

This doesn't work:

```
 <xsl:for-each  select="../Row[position() mod 2 =1]" />
```

Comment: Why is this tagged as [tag:jquery] and [tag:html]?

Comment: what's your processing context? why use ".." in `select`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [XSLT two column unordered list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14042573/xslt-two-column-unordered-list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your basic technique (using `position() mod 2`) is correct as demonstrated by the complete stylesheet below:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/dsQueryResponse/Rows">
        <xsl:for-each  select="Row[position() mod 2 = 1]">
            <xsl:value-of select="./@title"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Your problem is probably with the particular *context* you are in not being what you expect; but since you don't show the rest of your code we have no way of helping you.